# Can't get Secret Santa code to memorize assigned names

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, memory

I am a newbie in Python, I've learned some basic things like data types, cycles and how functions work so far. The thing is I don't know anything about databases...
I want to write a Secret Santa code to make a bot for me and my friends. The idea is that after you were invited to join the bot, you enter your name and surname and get assigned to a person (I need the surname part 'cos there are some people with the same name). After that the assigned name needs to be deleted from the initial 'targets' list, so it wouldn't be assigned to anyone else.
I've made the assignment part so far:

```
def appointer(name, surname):
template = "You are {}'s Secret Santa, congrats!"
targets = ['George Orwell', 'Vladimir Nabokov', 'Vladimir Sorokin']
        if name == 'George' and surname == 'Orwell':
                    targets.remove('George Orwell')
                    print(template.format(random.choice(targets)))
        elif name == 'Vladimir' and surname == 'Nabokov':
                    targets.remove('Vladimir Nabokov')
                    print(template.format(random.choice(targets)))
        elif name == 'Vladimir' and surname == 'Sorokin':
                    targets.remove('Vladimir Sorokin')
                    print(template.format(random.choice(targets)))
                    print(targets)
        else:
                    print('Wrong name, check again!')
```

(I need separate names and targets lists 'cos in my language names are declined.)
Yeah, that's how far I've got!
So the next step is for the bot to remember the assigned name and remove it from the 'targets' list so when the next person uses the bot he or she doesn't get the same name.
I've tried to make the assigned names get into the separate list and stuff, but it doesn't work due to multiple 'if' cycles.
So I've been wondering is there any way to get this thing done without resorting to databases?

**Here's an update:**

The plan to remember the assigned people via inbuilt dictionary didn't work and each time I run the code this dict resets to zero.
Then I've found a very useful *shelve module*.
So here's the code I've made with Tom's help:

```
import shelve

shelveFile = shelve.open('mydata')

import random

participants = [....]
template = "You're {}'s Secret Santa, congrats!"

def appointer(name, surname):
    fullname = name + ' ' + surname
    if fullname not in participants:
        print("Wrong name, check again!)
        return
    if fullname in shelveFile.keys():
        print("You already have your victim!")
        return
    options = [i for i in participants if i != fullname and i not in shelveFile.values()]
    selection = random.choice(options)
    shelveFile[fullname] = selection
    print(template.format(selection))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    appointer(name = input('Enter your name: ').lower().title(), surname = (input('Enter your surname:').lower().title()))

shelveFile.close()
```

Shelve module gives you an inbuilt database, and every time you run the code you still have the all the assigned people memorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good change to make would be to make `appointer` less explicit in checking cases.  You can use the `name` and `surname` arguments to dynamically check a name.  So instead of doing one `if` block for every name, you can do (within `appointer`):

```
fullname = name + ' ' + surname
```

As keeping track of everything, I reckon there are multiple decent ways to do so.  One possibility is to have a dictionary that links each participant to who they got.  So when ever you assign someone, you 1) filter their name out of the participants list, 2) filter out anyone who already has a Santa, 3) pick a new name, and 4) store the connection in the dictionary:

```
participants = ['George Orwell', 'Vladimir Nabokov', 'Vladimir Sorokin',
                'Mona Lisa', 'Tom Cruise', 'Stevie Nicks']
template = "You are {}'s Secret Santa, congrats!"
santas = {}

def appointer(name, surname):
    fullname = name + ' ' + surname
    if fullname not in participants:
        print('Wrong name, check again!')
        return # stop the function
    options = [i for i in participants if i != fullname and i not in santas.values()]
    selection = random.choice(options)
    santas[fullname] = selection
    print(template.format(selection))
```

So if you wanted to appoint everyone, you can do:

```
for i in participants:
    name, surname = i.split()
    appointer(name, surname)
```

And then inspect `santas` after to see who is assigned to who:

```
{'George Orwell': 'Stevie Nicks',
 'Vladimir Nabokov': 'George Orwell',
 'Vladimir Sorokin': 'Tom Cruise',
 'Mona Lisa': 'Vladimir Sorokin',
 'Tom Cruise': 'Mona Lisa',
 'Stevie Nicks': 'Vladimir Nabokov'}
```

Hopefully that wasn't stepping on your toes too much, good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! Your idea to dynamically check names was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
currentnonAssigneeslist = list()
allSecretSantaMember = list()


def appointer(firstName, lastName):
    # before assign check no duplicate entries
    if firstName + lastName not in currentnonAssigneeslist:
        currentnonAssigneeslist.append(firstName + lastName)
        randomlyAddSecretSanta(firstName, lastName)


def randomlyAddSecretSanta(firstName, lastName):
    # here should be the logic for assigning secret santa randomly
    currentnonAssigneeslist.remove(firstName + lastName)
    allSecretSantaMember.append(firstName + lastName)
    print(currentnonAssigneeslist)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    appointer("Sata", "x")
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_